# Get email when VM starts via Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to create a Azure Logic App that will send an email if a Virtual Machine gets started.  Is this possible and if so has anyone done this?

I've tried to modify the demo from the url [Monitor virtual machine changes with Azure Event Grid and Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app)

changing the condition to check for to

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['data']['operationName'], 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start')
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: try the following: 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action'

Comment: also, for the test purpose, try to filter all actions such as: 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter for Event Type "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess"

and check the condition:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['data']['operationName'], 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write'
```

Similar action can also be accomplished using Azure Automation in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/ensure-tags-exists-on-new-virtual-machines